# Getting specific part of text from file based on in-line date

Tags: shell, sh

I am not savvy at all when it comes to scripting. The script I have basically dumps the results of `git log` command into a file.

However, I would only like to show the lines for the day the script was run. So if I run myscript.sh on Thu Jun 20, I want to see all lines from a file down until Wed Jun 19.

Here is what the file looks like:

```
commit 8da0dd9bsd23899d11b4ee7348af0640b98ed4b17
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Thu Jun 20 12:08:59 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 6
    Multiple lines

commit aca564549f91329fcfa9a9f908f7fdeffa83f139b
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Thu Jun 20 12:01:48 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 5

commit b80c51b32f48364c2108588aff4c9e12fbb78370b
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Thu Jun 20 11:59:57 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 4

commit c4f8f8d4196f7c0f2deaf8g0ecc61797e7b8afdd9
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Wed Jun 19 11:48:37 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 3

commit 9a296b2273528868e3e4dc19310fa802daf76b1f3
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Wed Jun 19 11:45:49 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 2

commit 55cb8f2399242f051f577a042713a402137df4456
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Sat Jun 15 11:40:48 2013 -0400

    Testing Git push 13 1

commit a48e59ec1de227cc2878dce3330ge7776336eb289
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Thu Jun 13 11:28:56 2013 -0400

    Switched datasource to SuprPakJ
    Created WWButton and WWLabel (extends JButton and JLabel)
    Designed Sales Order screen

commit 57ce2da4673a35f50a5146d43a1f1a969c590c8c9
Author: Denis <Denis@WWOscar.Waudware.local>
Date:   Tue Jun 11 08:20:58 2013 -0400
```

I tried searching, but best I got was the `sed -e` command to print out everything until the first blank line, which isn't exactly what I need.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you:

```
git log --since=yesterday
```

Comment: That... works beautifully..! Can't thank you enough! But Thank You!